# Cloning multiple arraylists referencing the same objects

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, clone

I have an arraylist `a` containing certain objects. I also have an arraylist `b` containing arraylists containing some of these objects. Now, I want to clone the arraylist `a`, while updating the references in arraylist `b` to the cloned objects. A pseudo code example:

```
a = [object1,object2,object3,object4,object5,object6,object7,object8,object9,object10];
b = [[object3,object8,object5],[object2,object9,object1][object6,object7]];

//now, I can clone arraylist a
aClone = [clone1,clone2,clone3,clone4,clone5,clone6,clone7,clone8,clone9,clone10];

//but how do I get a clone of arraylist b containing references to the clones of the objects like so:
bClone = [[clone3,clone8,clone5],[clone2,clone9,clone1][clone6,clone7]];
```

Something I came up with is the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    o = a.get(i);
    aClone.set(i, o);
    for(int j = 0; j < b.length){
        for(int k = 0; k < b.get(j).length){
            if(b.get(j).get(k).value() == o.value())
                bClone.get(j).set(k, o);
        }
    }
}
```

This code checks after creating each clone if the old object is present in `b`, and replaces it with the clone. I imagine this would be extremely slow though, so does anyone know how this could be done more efficiently?

Comment: Not sure what kind of references you are talking about, but all I am seeing are primitives integers.

Comment: @MuratK. In my actual code I'm using objects. Here, I've used numbers to represent objects for the sake of clarity

Comment: Jonan, you have enough rep to know that you should also show us what have you tried and what are the issues you ran into...

Answer (score 1):

Just create a class like this:

```
class CloneRepository {
    private final Map<Object, Object> cloneMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

    public Object getClone(Object source) {
        Object result = cloneMap.get(source);

        if (result == null) {
            result = source.clone();
            cloneMap.put(source, result);
        }  

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then create a new CloneRepository(). When you clone the entries in each list, instead of cloning the object, use the getClone() method instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by holding wrapper classes in the lists, not direct references to the objects, then you can clone the wrapped object by calling a method like: 
`myWrapper.cloneObject().`

As the lists on `b` are holding the same references to the wrapper classes, when the objects are cloned, the 2 lists will be synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

with array a you can contain a hashmap - which position in the array for this object. Then when you clone your array a, you need to find an index of this object (HashMap does it for O(1) ) and change this reference. It will be for O(N) by summarize.